# ¿Cómo obtener el elemento de un array o lista en python?

Tags: python, django, anaconda

> Tengo el siguiente code, deseo obtener el elemento de **prediction[0]**, he usado numpy de la siguiente manera **np.argmax(prediction[0]**, pero me devuelve el índice, ver imagen. ¿ cómo puedo resolver el problema?, muchas gracias.

```
    prediction= (prediction > 0.5).astype(int)
    print('idx predict:',prediction)
    image_idx = np.argmax(prediction[0])
    print('Idx img: ',image_idx)
```

[image: Salida de code]

Answer (score 0):

espero te encuentres bien, te mostrare un ejemplo básico de como hacer esto normalmente espero lo puedas acoplar a tu código

```
import numpy as np

arreglo = np.array([9,8,7])
indice = np.argmax(arreglo)
print( "numero mayor del arreglo: ",arreglo[indice])
```

espero te sirva de ayuda, me gustaría saber más de la variable prediction, para brindar una mejor solución. ¡feliz días!

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó